# renderHeadrer does not pick up a change

Tags: reactjs, flags, glyphicons

So I have this code on React, I'm trying to get a glyphicon to change as direction of the sort changes.

I manged to get the direction flag from `null` to `asc` to `desc` and then back to `null`, using columnClicked

## PART OF THE CODE:

As part of this.state obj,:

```
    sortDirection: {
        url: null,
        size: null,
        time: null
    }
```

Then I have some functions that are already bound.

```
onColumnSort(dataKey, dir) {
    this.setState({sortKey: dataKey, sortDirection: dir})
}


columnClicked(dataKey){

        let sortDirections = this.state.sortDirection,
        dir = sortDirections[dataKey]

        if          (dir === null) {dir = 'asc'}    
        else if (dir === 'asc') { dir = 'desc'}         
        else if (dir === 'desc') { dir = null }

        // Reset sort           
        _.each(_.keys(sortDirections), function(x) {
            sortDirections[x] = null
        })
            sortDirections[dataKey] = dir

        if (this.props.onColumnSort) { 
            this.props.onColumnSort(dataKey, dir) 
        }
    }

RenderHeader(label, dataKey) {

        let dir = this.state.sortDirection[dataKey],
            classMap = {
              asc: 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes',
              desc: 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt',
            }
        console.log(classMap[dir]) // prints undefined

        let sortClass = dir ? classMap[dir] : 'See me?'

        console.log(dir) // prints null

        console.log(sortClass) // prints the string set See me?
    return (
        <div className="text-primary sortable"
            onClick={() => this.columnClicked(dataKey)}>
            <strong>{label}</strong>
            &nbsp;
            <i className={sortClass}></i>
        </div>
    )
}
```

The problem is that renderHeadrer does not pick up the change, and always results in `classMap[null`] which prints no glyph instead of doing `classMap[asc]`, `classMap[desc]` and then `classMap[null]`, so I can tell the glyph classMap object is not being used at all as the `func` is not actually picking the flag. But I don't see what's wrong.

I have been trying make this work for hours and cant' seem to get it right.
Any pointers would be great and very helpful. Cheers.

## EDIT

component 1 going into component 2

## 1

```
import  React, {Component} from 'react'
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import 'fixed-data-table/dist/fixed-data-table.css'
// import FixedDataTable from 'fixed-data-table-2'
import FixedDataTable from 'fixed-data-table'
import {Grid, Row, Col, PageHeader, Button, ButtonGroup, 
                FormGroup, FormControl, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'
import _ from 'lodash'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

'use strict'
const {Table, Column, Cell, rowIndex, 
            columnKey, data, field} = FixedDataTable
const GutterWidth = 30


export default class HarEntryTable extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super() 
        this.state = {
            isColumnResizing: false,
            columnWidths: {
                url:500,
                size:200,
                time:200
            },
            sortDirection: {
                url: null,
                size: null,
                time: null
            },
            tableWidth:1000,
            tableHeight: 500
        }
        this._onColumnResized = this._onColumnResized.bind(this)
        this._onResize = this._onResize.bind(this)
        this._getEntry =  this._getEntry.bind(this)
        this._readKey =  this._readKey.bind(this)
        this._columnClicked =  this._columnClicked.bind(this)
        this._RenderHeader =  this._RenderHeader.bind(this)

    }
    _readKey(key, entry) {
        let keyMap = {
            url: 'request.url',
            time: 'time.start'
        }
        //size is not inside keyMap so it's key is passed instead
        key = keyMap[key] || key
        return _.get(entry, key)
    }

    _getEntry(index) {
        return this.props.entries[index] 
    }

    _onResize() {
        // automatically adjustment of width and height of table
        // let parent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).parentNode  
        let parent = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.entriesTable).parentNode 
        this.setState({
            tableWidth: parent.clientWidth - GutterWidth,
            tableHeight: document.body.clientHeight - 
                                     parent.offsetTop - GutterWidth * 0.5
        })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let global = window
        // you debounce something that repeats a lot
        global.addEventListener('resize', 
            _.debounce(this._onResize), 50, {leading : true, trailing: true})
            this._onResize()
    }

    _onColumnResized(newColumnWidth, columnKey) { 
        let columnWidths = this.state.columnWidths
        // Select the col by key, then  the new col 
        // width can be set anything, this case 
        // is called newColumnWidth... could be x
        columnWidths[columnKey] = newColumnWidth
        this.setState({columnWidths: columnWidths, isResizable:false})
    }

    _columnClicked(dataKey) {
        let sortDirections = this.state.sortDirection,
                dir = sortDirections[dataKey]
        if          (dir === null) {dir = 'asc'}    
        else if (dir === 'asc') { dir = 'desc'}         
        else if (dir === 'desc') { dir = null }

        // Reset sort           
        _.each(_.keys(sortDirections), function(x) {
            sortDirections[x] = null
        })
            sortDirections[dataKey] = dir

        if (this.props.onColumnSort) { 
            this.props.onColumnSort(dataKey, dir) 
        }
    }

    _RenderHeader(label, dataKey) {
        let dir = this.state.sortDirection[dataKey],
            classMap = {
              asc: 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes',
              desc: 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort-by-attributes-alt',
            }
        // console.log(classMap[dir])
        let sortClass = dir ? classMap[dir] : 'See me?'
        // console.log(dir)
        // console.log(sortClass)
        // let sortClass = 'glyphicon glyphicon-sort'
        

        return (
            <div className="text-primary sortable"
                onClick={() => this._columnClicked(dataKey)}>
                <strong>{label}</strong>
                &nbsp;
                <i className={sortClass}></i>
            </div>
        )
    }

    render() {
        return (                    
            <Table  ref="entriesTable" 
                          rowsCount={this.props.entries.length}
                            width={this.state.tableWidth} 
                            headerHeight={35} 
                            height={this.state.tableHeight}
                            rowHeight={30}
                            rowGetter={this._getEntry}
                            isColumnResizing={this.state.isColumnResizing}
                            onColumnResizeEndCallback={this._onColumnResized}
                            >
                <Column header={<Cell>Url</Cell>}
                              headerRenderer={this._RenderHeader}
                                label='Url'
                                columnKey='url'
                                dataKey="url"
                                cellDataGetter={this._readKey} 
                                width={this.state.columnWidths.url}
                                isResizable={true}
                                flexGrow={null} />                          
                <Column header={<Cell>Size</Cell>} 
                              headerRenderer={this._RenderHeader}
                                label='Size'
                                columnKey="size"
                                dataKey="size"
                                width={this.state.columnWidths.size}
                                cellDataGetter={this._readKey} 
                                isResizable={true} />                           
            <Column   header={<Cell>TimeLine</Cell>}
                              headerRenderer={this._RenderHeader}
                                label='TimeLine'
                                columnKey="time"
                                dataKey="time"
                                width={this.state.columnWidths.time}
                                cellDataGetter={this._readKey} 
                                minWidth={200}
                                isResizable={true} />
            </Table>        
        )
    }
}

HarEntryTable.defaultProps = {
    entries: [],
    page: null,
    onColumnSort: null
}

HarEntryTable.porpType =  {
    entries: PropTypes.array,
    onColumnSort: PropTypes.func,
    page: PropTypes.object
}
```

## 2

```
import  ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import  React, {Component, PorpTypes} from 'react'
import _ from 'lodash'
import mimeTypes from '../Core/mimeTypes.js'
import {Grid, Row, Col, PageHeader, Button, ButtonGroup, 
                FormGroup, FormControl, Alert} from 'react-bootstrap'
import HarEntryTable from './HarEntryTable.jsx'
import harParser from '../Core/harParser.js'

'use strict'
export default class HarViewer extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super() 
        this.state =    this._initialState()
        
        this._sampleChanged = this._sampleChanged.bind(this)
        this._filterdTextChanged = this._filterdTextChanged.bind(this)
        this._filterRequested = this._filterRequested.bind(this)
        this._renderHeader = this._renderHeader.bind(this)
        this._initialState = this._initialState.bind(this)
        this._renderViewer = this._renderViewer.bind(this)
        this._renderEmptyViewer = this._renderEmptyViewer.bind(this)
        this._onColumnSort = this._onColumnSort.bind(this)
    }

// ___________________
//      METHODS TO USE  |
// ___________________|

    _initialState() {
        return {
            activeHar: null,
            sortKey: null,
            sortDirection: null
        }
    }

    _sampleChanged() {
        let selection = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.selector).value
        let har =  selection 
            ? _.find(window.samples, s => s.id === selection).har
            : null
            if(har) {
                this.setState({activeHar: har})
            }
            else {
                this.setState(this._initialState())
            }
    }

    _filterRequested(type, event) {}

    _filterdTextChanged() {}

    _onColumnSort(dataKey, dir) {
        // this.setState({sortKey: dataKey, sortDirection: dir})
        const nextSortkey = Object.assign({}, this.state.sortKey, dataKey)
        const sortDirection = Object.assign({}, this.state.sortDirection, dir)
        this.setState({sortKey: nextSortkey, sortDirection: sortDirection})  
    }

    _sortEntriesByKey(sortKey, sortDirection, entries) {
        if(_.isEmpty(sortKey) | _.isEmpty(sortDirection)) return entries
            let keyMap = {
                url: 'request.url',
                time: 'time.start'
                },
                getValue = function(entry) {
                    let key = keyMap[sortKey] || sortKey
                    return _.get(entry, key)
            }
            let sorted =  _.sortBy(entries, getValue)
            if (sortDirection === 'desc') {
                sorted.reverse()
            }
            return sorted
    }

    _createButton(type, label) {
        var handler = this._filterRequested(type)
        return (
            <Button key={type}
                            bsStyle="primary"
                            active={this.state.type === type}
                            onClick={handler}> { label }
            </Button>   
        )
    }

    render() {
        let content = this.state.activeHar
                                        ? this._renderViewer(this.state.activeHar)
                                        : this._renderEmptyViewer() 

        return (    
            <div>
                {this._renderHeader()}
                {content}
            </div>
        )
    }

    _renderEmptyViewer() {
        return(
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <p></p>
                        <Alert bsStyle="warning">
                            <strong>No HAR loaded</strong>
                        </Alert>
                    </Col>
                </Row>      
            </Grid>             
        )
    }

    _renderViewer(har) {
        let pages = harParser.parse(har), 
                currentPage = pages[0]

        let entries = this._sortEntriesByKey(this.state.sortKey, 
                                    this.state.sortDirection, 
                                    currentPage.entries)
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <HarEntryTable entries={entries} 
                        onColumnSort={this._onColumnSort}/>
                    </Col>
                </Row>      
            </Grid>             
        )
    }

    // renderHeader is returning the Grid
    _renderHeader() {
        const buttons = _.map(_.keys(mimeTypes.types), (x) => {
            return this._createButton(x, mimeTypes.types[x].label)
        })
        //populate the select component
        const options = _.map(window.samples, (s) => {
            return ( <option key={s.id} value={s.id} > {s.label} </option> )
        })
        return (
            <Grid>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="pageHeader" sm={12}>
                        <PageHeader>HarViewer</PageHeader>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col sm={12}>
                        <p>PIE CHART</p>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col className="margined" sm={4}>
                        <div>
                            <label className="control-label"></label>
                            <select ref="selector" className="form-control" 
                                onChange={this._sampleChanged}>
                                <option value="">-----</option>
                                {options}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                        <Col sm={8}>
                            <ButtonGroup bsSize="large">
                                {this._createButton('all', 'All')}
                                {buttons}
                            </ButtonGroup> 
                        </Col>
                        <Col sm={4}>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <FormControl type="search"
                                                          placeholder="Search URL"
                                                          bsSize="small"
                                                          onChange={this._filterdTextChanged}
                                                          inputRef={ ref => { this.input = ref } } />
                            </FormGroup>                                                          
                        </Col>
                </Row>
            </Grid>
        )
    }
}

HarViewer.defaultProps = {
    entries: []
}
```

Sorry about the length...

Comment: it seems like you are mutating the state. try using `Object.assign`: 
`const nextSortKey = Object.assign({},this.state.sortKey, dataKey);`
`const sortDirection = Object.assign({},this.state.sortDirection, dir);`
`this.setState({},{sortKey: nextSortKey , sortDirection: sortDirection })`

Comment: Could you please add the whole component?  Currently I am not sure if you have methods split into 1 or 2 components. You are sending events up using `props.onColumnSort` but you are then reading just the local `this.state`.

Comment: There are actually two components.. See edit pls. I tried making a copy of the object following @Sag1v 's suggestion but the functionality broke